# Flutter : No devices

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to run Flutter demo app for the first time in Android Studio.
I have installed up all settings for flutter in Android Studio and now I am trying to run the app in emulator but it keeps saying 'no devices' even though emulator is running.

I have tried
flutter doctor --android-licenses
flutter doctor
all set up variables in user setting
installed all sdk properly in proper path[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCk6d.jpg)

Comment: Did you try closing the emulator's window and running it again ?

Comment: Yes I have tried closing and running again the emulator million times :(

Comment: Did you tried to restart emulator and adb both? Try "adb kill-server" command.

Comment: sometimes it takes a while until the emulator is detected (a minute)

Comment: Sometimes, Flutter won't discover devices if there are problems in Android or Dart SDKs, run `flutter doctor` and see if there are issues with the SDKs

Answer (score 0):

It may be related with your Android emulator, you can try to create new one.(It is weird but solved my problem once)

and be sure about the device is active, In your console type `adb devices` and you should see your android emulator like following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go tools -> Avd manager -> then install an emulator if u didn't , then install a system image .

Documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Answer (score 0):

you can drag debug apk file that you find in (Your App location)\build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk and put it on android emulator and it will install it and run it

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple step to solve this. Just click on project Structure which you will find near **Search icon** on Android studio toolbar and before your profile icon, you will find project structure. Click on it and select **Project SDK** And press Ok. You will find that your device is now showing.