# <no devices> cant select any Emulators to run code

Tags: android, flutter, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run the flutter demo app. I have already installed the android sdk and avd. I can get the emulator to run from clicking on open android emulator as seen below. However i cannot get the demo code to run with the emulator selected.

[image: image1]

[image: image1]

Any help will be appreciated

[Flutter : No devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891596/flutter-no-devices)
[I have installed an emulator]

I have gotten the emulator set up

```
1 available emulator:

Nexus_5_API_28 • Nexus 5 API 28 • Google • android
```

Comment: what is the result of  `flutter doctor`

Comment: check that the minSdkVersion of the project is lower than the one of your emulator

Answer (score 1):

Can you check for these things.

1. Run Flutter-doctor. Fix any issues shown.
2. Check for the plugins for flutter and dart are upto date.
3. Check for environment variables %ANDROID_HOME% and if path has %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools set and point to correct installation directory. This is needed in case you do not install in default installation folder.
4. Restart IDE and any open console windows.

[Flutter Install guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Answer (score 0):

Flutter identifies the emulator/simulator when it is in background/active. 
If emulator/simulator not in background,
Flutter devices in the terminal result as shown below

***No devices detected.
Run 'flutter emulators' to list and start any available device emulators.***

Emulator can't open outside android studio as per my knowledge. With iOS simulator, you might get clarity. Open simulator and do flutter devices in the terminal shows as

***1 connected device:
iPhone Xʀ • ios •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)***

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the AVD does not have Google Play.