# How do I get my virtual device to show on the "device selected" dropdown menu in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I have my emulator running, I am unable to select the virtual device from the dropdown menu where it initially says `"<no device selected>".` Please can someone tell me how I can resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do see any issue while running `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<no devices> cant select any Emulators to run code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669517/no-devices-cant-select-any-emulators-to-run-code)