# Flutter: Intellij does show no device (but no problem in Android Project)

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart, android-emulator

I am trying to set up Flutter in Intellij (2020.1 Community Edition). I installed Dart and Flutter as plug-ins. I also have installed the Flutter SDK as well as the Android SDK.

After downloading an android virtual device (Pixel 2 XL API 27) I wanted to try out to run the Flutter template app, but it fails to recognize the emulator. When I create an Android Project and try to run it with an emulator it runs without any problems.

This post ([Flutter : No devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891596/flutter-no-devices)) did not provide me with anything useful.

Comment: Is your virtual device up and running?

Comment: @Blasanka: Yes it was running. And I solved the issue by setting the Project SDK to the Android SDK. Don't know why there is no special Flutter SDK to select.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved the issue. I went to `File > Project Structure > Project`. At Project SDK I selected `Android API 28 Platform`. Then click Apply and Ok to finish this process. After doing this step you can select the device.

Answer (score 9):

Intellij does that a lot in my system. You had to check Flutter path is set in `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Flutter`
and Android SDK is set to Android API 29 Platform in `File > Project Structure > Project`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do both the fixes suggested by @MachineLerner and @theshivamlko when I wanted to connect to a physical device:

1. Ensure Flutter path is set in `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter`.
2. Ensure `Android SDK` is set to Android API 29 Platform in `File > Project Structure > Project`

And then also had to Run IntelliJ IDEA as an Administrator.

Comment: please expand this into a standalone answer.